# How do I validate data table values using selenium against the API response?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

Steps : 
1. UI Interacts with DB using Webservice /API Layer 
2. Will extract a data table using selenium and need to compare against the json response by API Layer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for solutions for test data management, might get more joy if u post on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/...